# When I run the test “ rspec spec/cart_spec.rb ”In the console, I'll get a warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

**When I run the test “ rspec spec/cart_spec.rb ”In the console, I'll get a warning**

```
    require 'rspec'
    require_relative '../app/item'
    require_relative '../app/virtual_item'
    require_relative '../app/antique_item'
    require_relative '../app/item_container'
    require_relative '../app/cart'

    describe Cart do

      it 'add items into the cart' do
        cart = Cart.new('')
        item1 = Item.new('kettle', price: 200)
        item2 = Item.new('car', price: 200)
        cart.add_items(item1, item2)
        cart.items.should include(item1, item2)
      end

    end
```

**In the console, I'll get a warning**

```
E:\work\storeapp\spec>rspec spec/cart_spec.rb
c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load': cannot load such file -- E:/work/storeapp/spec/spec/cart_s
pec.rb (LoadError)
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
        from c:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

![enter image description here][1]

**where is my mistake?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that it can't find the spec file and indeed you're pointing to

```
spec/cart_spec.rb
```

... while in the `spec` directory. To find it from there you need to remove `spec/`:

```
rspec cart_spec.rb
```

My usual practice is to run specs from the app root. From there, your original command should work. Or you can just use an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Comment: thank you it works))) I'm just learning and so are the following errors